# Traversing a hierarchical List/Tree having reference to parent node in Java

Tags: java, android, algorithm, tree

I am trying to create a Hierarchical menu using https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView

I would be retrieving my data from a REST service and a sample menu would look like below

```
[
  {
    "name": "parent 1",
    "code": "p1",
    "parent_code": "null",
    "is_active": 1,
    "store_id": "57a6d06232a7d133002b838c"
  },
  {
    "name": "parent 2",
    "code": "p2",
    "parent_code": "null",
    "is_active": 1,
    "store_id": "57a6d06232a7d133002b838c"
  },
  {
    "name": "child 1",
    "code": "c1",
    "parent_code": "p1",
    "is_active": 1,
    "store_id": "57a6d06232a7d133002b838c"
  },
  {
    "name": "child 2",
    "code": "c2",
    "parent_code": "p1",
    "is_active": 1,
    "store_id": "57a6d06232a7d133002b838c"
  },
  {
    "name": "grand child 1",
    "code": "gc1",
    "parent_code": "c2",
    "is_active": 1,
    "store_id": "57a6d06232a7d133002b838c"
  },
  {
    "name": "grand child 2",
    "code": "gc2",
    "parent_code": "c2",
    "is_active": 0,
    "store_id": "57a6d06232a7d133002b838c"
  },
  {
    "name": "grand child 3",
    "code": "gc3",
    "parent_code": "c2",
    "is_active": 1,
    "store_id": "57a6d06232a7d133002b838c"
  }
]
```

I am trying to traverse the List and create a Hierarchical menu. I am traversing using the following code

```
for (ProductCategory prodCat :
                productCategories)
{
    if (prodCat.getParentCode().equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
    {
        // I found a parent node
        for (ProductCategory prodCatChild :
                productCategories)
        {
            if (prodCatChild.getParentCode().equalsIgnoreCase(prodCat.getCategoryCode()))
            {
                //I found all child nodes of the current parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My ProductCategory is defined as below

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    private String categoryName;

    private String categoryCode;

    private String parentCode;

    private Boolean isActive;

    private String storeId;
}
```

This piece of code has two issues.

- If there is a third level or more in the tree, I will not be able to traverse them at all.
- I am traversing n^2 times just for two levels.

How can I traverse having only reference to parent in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advice you to use the Hash Map data structure in order to construct the tree with *O(N)* runtime complexity.

For simplicity, let's assume that your entities have the following structure (for the sake of simplicity I'm also violating the encapsulation principle inside the provided snippets of code):

```
class Item {

    // id of the item itself
    final String id;

    // id of the parent item
    final String parentId;

    // this list will contain the children of the given item
    // at the beginning this list is empty, and we are going to populate it
    final List<Item> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public Item(String id, String parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

In order to construct the tree you should maintain the mapping from item id to the item itself (which can be done using the *java.util.HashMap* data structure). After construction of the mapping, you can attach every node to its parent:

```
List<Item> constructForest(Item... items) {
    Map<String, Item> itemIdToItem = indexItemsById(items);
    List<Item> roots = attachToParents(itemIdToItem, items);
    return roots;
}

/**
 * Index all items by item id.
 * Returns the mapping from the item id to item.
 */
Map<String, Item> indexItemsById(Item... items) {
    Map<String, Item> itemIdToItem = new HashMap<>();
    for (Item item : items) {
        itemIdToItem.put(item.id, item);
    }
    return itemIdToItem;
}

/**
 * Attaches the children nodes to the parent nodes
 * Returns the list of root nodes of the constructed forest
 */
List<Item> attachToParents(Map<String, Item> itemIdToItem, Item... items) {

    List<Item> roots = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Item item : items) {
        if (item.parentId == null) {
            roots.add(item);
        } else {
            Item parent = itemIdToItem.get(item.parentId);
            parent.children.add(item);
        }
    }

    return roots;
}
```

The runtime complexity of the provided code is *O(N)*.

Now, having the list of roots of the constructed trees, you can traverse them using any of the tree traversal algorithms, e.g. Breadth-first search (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), Depth-first search (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), which also have the runtime complexity *O(N)*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your inputs. I wanted to understand if the approach that I have taken to achieve this is wrong? My approach is to not have child elements as part of parent node, but to have them as a separate node with reference to parent node.

Comment: @rakesh kashyap if you don't want, that parent nodes contain lists of child elements, you can use either Adjacency matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) or Adjacency list (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) in order to decouple the information about the edges of your tree from the parent nodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments and directions